# set up centos7, configuration of ip

Tags: centos, ip

when I'm searching for ip setting of centos 7. Responed is centos 6.X 's or ealier, and I tried. But how is the default DHCP configuration of centos 7.
Some configurations have been done like
[image]

I want the os can get ip infomation by dhcp!!

Comment: the above configuration isn't work

Comment: Two main things is that you're configuring dhcp on the loopback interface and the other is that `NetworkManager` is configured to control it so the `ifcfg` files don't matter if `NetworkManager` wants to do something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are trying to configure `lo` interface to use DHCP. `lo` is a loopback device, virtual network interface that your computer uses to communicate with itself.

You need to find out the name of your network interface card by running `ifconfig -a` command and then creating a configuration file for it in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts`.

Here is an example from my machine.

```
[root@insomnia ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp6s0 
DEVICE=enp6s0
HWADDR=00:1f:bc:08:69:82
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
[root@insomnia ~]# ifconfig enp6s0
enp6s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::21f:bcff:fe08:6982  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:1f:bc:08:69:82  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 18901  bytes 5088525 (4.8 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 14492  bytes 2839283 (2.7 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

You can also reference [this Red Hat Networking Guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/index.html) as Red Hat Enterprise Linux is identical to CentOS.

Answer (score 0):

Use command setup---> Network configuration ---> Device Configuration ---> Eth0 --> Check Use DHCP.

Exit and save, then type `service network restart`.